# I need to escape! Angular $sce not handling links to audio files (Strict Contextual Escaping)

Tags: html, angularjs, audio, escaping

I have Angular and `$sce` working on my project for displaying HTML special characters, and for a video player's links to video files in my database. But I can't get `$sce` to connect the HTML audio player to audio files on the same database.

This HTML works:

```
<audio controls ng-src="https://mydatabase.com/aa6df923">
```

This is the project HTML:

```
<audio controls ng-src="{{audioSource}}">
```

This doesn't work:

```
$scope.audioSource = "https://mydatabase.com/aa6df923";
```

This also doesn't work:

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.audioSource = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("https://mydatabase.com/aa6df923");
});
```

This doesn't work either:

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.audioSource = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("https://mydatabase.com/aa6df923");
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

Not this one either:

```
$scope.audioSource = "../audio/myFile.mp3";
```

And, finally, this filter works to escape HTML special characters but don't work to link the audio files:

```
<audio controls ng-src="{{audioSource | trustAsHtml}}">

app.filter('trustAsHtml', [$sce', function($sce) {
    return function(html) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
    };
}]);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried it with a lowercase hostname -
 `https://mydatabase.com/aa6df923`? You could also try `$sceDelegateProvider` to whitelist the resource URL in your `.config()`.

Comment: I made up that URL. The real URL is all lower case. Whitelisting shouldn't be needed because the same database works to provide videos to the video player.

Comment: You can "whitelist" the domain using [`$sceDelegateProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$sceDelegateProvider) so that all of the content from the matching pattern is valid as a resource URL. It would look something like this `$sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['self', 'https://mydatabase.com/**']);` in your `app.config()`.

Comment: Did you create a new filter based on `trustAsHtml` for `trustAsResourceUrl`?

Comment: And `https://mydatabase.com/aa6df923` represents a link to an MP3 file served over SSL, for example?

Comment: No, I didn't create a new filter for $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(value). This is a method of $sce.

Comment: I know, you have an example of a custom filter at the bottom of your question for `trustAsHtml`, did you also create a filter for the `$sce.trustAsResourceUrl()` method?

Comment: I don't have an app.config file.

Comment: Meant to say `angular.module('app').config()` which it looks like you have defined as `app`.

Comment: Yes, the mp3 file works fine, in the first configuration. The database is SSL.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new filter called `trustAsResourceUrl` that will work the same as your `trustAsHtml` example.

***Create a `trustAsResourceUrl` filter:***

```
app.filter('trustAsResourceUrl', ['$sce', function($sce) {
    return function(url) {
        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
    };
}]);
```

> *note that there is a typo in your example - a `(` between `return` and `function`*

***Use the filter in your template:***

```
<audio controls ng-src="{{ audioSource | trustAsResourceUrl }}">
```

Keep in mind this will trust *every* URL you pass to the filter.

If you just want to whitelist a domain you can do this in your `app.config()`.

```
angular.module('app')
.config(['$sceDelegateProvider', function($sceDelegateProvider) {
  // whitelist resource URLs
  $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
    'self',
    'https://mydatabase.com/**'
  ]);
}]);
```

Otherwise the code in your earlier examples should work, assuming the domains match, etc. If these solutions don't fix your issue you it would be helpful to post the full error you are seeing in the console.

Comment: OK, I made a .config module and put in 'self' and '$sceDelegateProvider.' The audio files still don't link. Thanks for pointing out the typo, it wasn't in my file (I typed the question code rather than copy and paste).

Answer (score 0):

I've started to figure it out. `$scope.audioSource` is inside a function, which puts it on a new `$scope`. I.e., `{{audioSource}}` and `$scope.audioSource` are on different scopes. I'll work on returning values out of functions and onto the controller's `$scope`.